Using linux's perf tool with Python virtual environnent
Assume the following setup:
source -- "<some_python_venv_directory>/bin/activate"
perf record -- python3 test.py

The python3 binary is expected to be the one in ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin. But due to perf's sneaky prepend to the PATH environment variable:
basically it does export PATH=/usr/libexec/perf-core:/usr/bin:${PATH}
The python3 I end up using is /usr/bin/python3. The issue is that the venv is built for a Python 3.11 which is different from the Python 3.6 I have in /usr/bin.
I was wondering:

where this perf behavior is documented;
why it does it;
and apart from using "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/python3", what can be done to avoid this issue?

